# Azure Function Trigger Name/Connections from App Configuration

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-app-configuration

Is there now a way to set the Trigger Properties(Name/Connection) using the value from Azure App Configuration?.

I added a startup class that reads the data from Azure App Configuration but it seems the trigger set its properties earlier than that, therefore not able to bind the data that came from the app configuration.

I also found this thread about it but im not sure if there is a new update?:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/63419
https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/issues/203

Comment: Hi!, Could you please share some code? Are you deploying to a app service ? In that case I would advice  you try to connect to the deployed app service via ```kudu``` ( advance settings console ) and from the cmd console write a ```set``` command to check how your appservice environment variable name expects to be named, because there is a mismatch between the local development and the deployed environment. Check that for example n the case of SQL connection string forthe appservice expects a environment variable called something like SQLCONNSTR_{x}, but locally is called just {x}

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. The following code gets the name of the queue to monitor from an app setting, and it gets the queue message creation time in the `insertionTime` parameter:

```
public static class BindingExpressionsExample
{
    [FunctionName("LogQueueMessage")]
    public static void Run(
        [QueueTrigger("%queueappsetting%")] string myQueueItem,
        DateTimeOffset insertionTime,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Message content: {myQueueItem}");
        log.LogInformation($"Created at: {insertionTime}");
    }
}
```

*Similarly, you can use this approach for other triggers.*

Comment: where did %queueappsetting% came from. coudl you show your appsettings?

Comment: Check out this MS Doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#binding-expressions-example

Comment: Does this help you?

Comment: thanks but nope. what im looking for is to get the data from the Azure App Configuration and use that in the binding value attributes of the function.

Comment: Okay, got it. Then read all setting from App configuration in static constructor and use it here in `Run`

Comment: I did it that way already. What will happen is you can use the app configurations inside the "BODY" of the function, but if you use it in the "function trigger parameters" it always results to null.

Comment: @user2572367 Did you find a way to make this work?

Comment: @ryansan not yet